# UITextView scrolls to top on hiding keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: uiscrollview, ios8, uitextview

My UITextView uses attributet text.
When I call resignFirstResponder it always scrolls to the top.

This only happens on my iOS 8 Simulator. Not my iOS 7 phone.

Any idea to prevent this?

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for two days and have not found one. This bug is highly frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a work around to this.

First, instead of calling `resignFirstResponder` I'm now calling `[textView setEditable:NO]` to dismiss the keyboard.

There seems to be a bug when initializing UITextViews in iOS 8. Long story short, the subview (of my UITextView) UITextContainerView's minSize Y value was not being initialized to the same size as the UITextView's frame. It was set to 0 instead.

To force an initialization of that value, since it's not directly accessible, I found that calling `[textView setScrollEnabled:NO]` in `viewDidLoad` will set that Y to the same as my frame's size Y value, which fixed a lot of my scrolling issues in iOS 8.

I also had to set the scrolling back to enabled in `viewDidAppear` so that they'd still be scrollable.

Comment: look in like in by set scrollEanbled to NO in viewDidLoad and set back to YES in viewDidAppear fixes the problem, resignFirstResponder is also fixed.

Comment: BTW that was an amazing fix, been looking for days to fix various problems caused by this bug, Thank you!!!!